# Select Json formatted like a report to a table using T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have JSON stored in a SQL Server database table in the below format. I have been able to fudge a way to get the values I need but feel like there must be a better way to do it using T-SQL. The JSON is output from a report in the below format where the column names in "columns" correspond to the "rows"-"data" array values.

So column "Fiscal Month" corresponds to data value "11", "Fiscal Year" to "2019", etc.

```
{
  "report": "Property ETL",
  "id": 2648,
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Fiscal Month",
      "dataType": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fiscal Year",
      "dataType": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Portfolio",
      "dataType": "varchar(50)"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rent",
      "dataType": "int"
    }
],
"rows": [
    {
      "rowName": "1",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "West Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "2",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "East Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "3",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "East Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "Totals: ",
      "type": "Total",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        30
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to get at the data in the 'data' array I currently have a 2 step process in T-SQL where I create a temp table, and insert the row key/values from '$.Rows' there. Then I can then select the individual columns for each row

```
CREATE TABLE #TempData 
(
    Id INT,
    JsonData VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @LineageKey INT;

SET @json = (SELECT JsonString FROM Stage.Report);
SET @LineageKey = (SELECT LineageKey FROM Stage.Report);    

INSERT INTO #TempData(Id, JsonData)
    (SELECT [key], value FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.rows'))

MERGE [dbo].[DestinationTable] TARGET
USING 
(
    SELECT 
        JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.data[0]') AS FiscalMonth,
        JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.data[1]') AS FiscalYear,
        JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.data[2]') AS Portfolio,
        JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.data[3]') AS Rent
     FROM #TempData
     WHERE JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.data[0]') is not null
) AS SOURCE     
... 
etc., etc.
```

This works, but I want to know if there is a way to directly select the data values without the intermediate step of putting it into the temp table. The documentation and examples I've read seem to all require that the data have a name associated with it in order to access it. When I try and access the data directly at a position by index I just get Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. If you know the columns names you need one `OPENJSON()` call with explicit schema, but if you want to read the JSON structure from `$.columns`, you need a dynamic statement.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
  "report": "Property ETL",
  "id": 2648,
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Fiscal Month",
      "dataType": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fiscal Year",
      "dataType": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Portfolio",
      "dataType": "varchar(50)"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rent",
      "dataType": "int"
    }
],
"rows": [
    {
      "rowName": "1",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "West Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "2",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "East Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "3",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "East Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "Totals: ",
      "type": "Total",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        30
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

Statement for fixed structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.rows') WITH (
   [Fiscal Month] int '$.data[0]',
   [Fiscal Year] int '$.data[1]',
   [Portfolio] varchar(50) '$.data[2]',
   [Rent] int '$.data[3]'
)
```

Dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''

SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
   @stm,
   N',',
   QUOTENAME(j2.name),
   N' ',
   j2.dataType,
   N' ''$.data[',
   j1.[key],
   N']'''
)
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.columns') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) WITH (
   name varchar(50) '$.name',
   dataType varchar(50) '$.dataType'
) j2

SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
   N'SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, ''$.rows'') WITH (',
   STUFF(@stm, 1, 1, N''),
   N')'
)
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm, N'@json nvarchar(max)', @json
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------------
Fiscal Month    Fiscal Year Portfolio   Rent
--------------------------------------------
11              2019        West Group  10
11              2019        East Group  10
11              2019        East Group  10
                                        30
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible without temporary table:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'
{
  "report": "Property ETL",
  "id": 2648,
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Fiscal Month",
      "dataType": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fiscal Year",
      "dataType": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Portfolio",
      "dataType": "varchar(50)"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rent",
      "dataType": "int"
    }
],
"rows": [
    {
      "rowName": "1",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "West Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "2",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "East Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "3",
      "type": "Detail",
      "data": [
        11,
        2019,
        "East Group",
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "rowName": "Totals: ",
      "type": "Total",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        30
      ]
    }
  ]
}    
}';
```

And query:

```
SELECT s.value,
  rowName = JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.rowName'),
  [type] = JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.type'),
  s2.[key],
  s2.value
FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.rows')) s
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(s.value, '$.data')) s2;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=989cea13e44a961667eb901d17c62974)**

Or as a single row per detail:

```
SELECT s.value,
  rowName = JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.rowName'),
  [type] = JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.type'),
  JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.data[0]') AS FiscalMonth,
  JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.data[1]') AS FiscalYear,
  JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.data[2]') AS Portfolio,
  JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.data[3]') AS Rent
FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.rows')) s;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e487a3bbb6bbb54b50b4f11f3f90d561)**